# How to prevent dynamicLink listener from firing multiple times in react-native?

Tags: react-native, firebase-authentication, firebase-dynamic-links, react-native-firebase

I have enabled `signInWithEmailLink()` from firebase in my react-native app.

Everything works successfully, the user is also created but the I think the `onLink(handleLink)` listener is fired multiple times and leads to an error even after user sign-in.

Logs:

```
link is tru
 LOG  email:  email@gmail.com //I have hidden the actual email
 LOG  email:  email@gmail.com
 LOG  email:  email@gmail.com
 LOG  USer created
 LOG  EROR:  [Error: [auth/invalid-action-code] The out of band code is invalid. This can happen if the code is malformed, expired, or has already been used.]
 LOG  EROR:  [Error: [auth/invalid-action-code] The out of band code is invalid. This can happen if the code is malformed, expired, or has already been used.]
 LOG  EROR:  [Error: [auth/invalid-action-code] The out of band code is invalid. This can happen if the code is malformed, expired, or has already been used.]
```

As you can see its fired multiple times, how can I prevent this??

This is my code:

```js
const handleLink = async link => {
  console.log('opened Link: ', link.url);
  if (auth().isSignInWithEmailLink(link.url)) {
    console.log('link is tru');
    try {
      const email = await AsyncStorage.getItem('email');
      console.log('email: ', email);
      await auth()
        .signInWithEmailLink(`${email}`, link.url)
        .then(() => {
          console.log('USer created');
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log('EROR: ', err);
        });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log('err: ', err);
    }
  } else {
    console.log('link is false');
  }
};

const link = dynamicLinks().onLink(handleLink);
```

Help would be very much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Since `console.log('email: ', email);` is called 3 times, i assume that `console.log('link is tru');` is also called 3 times, so the problem is that the whole `handleLink` function is called 3 times before `auth().signInWithEmailLink` finishes.

Comment: Yes, you’re right but how should I prevent this from happening?

Comment: The place you're calling `dynamicLinks().onLink(handleLink)` is wrong i guess. Try putting it componentDidMount of your App component, so that it only executes once

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue here is the answer.

`Email link Authentication has a longer expiration time (around 6 hours). If you'll create 2 or more sign in emails in a row, you should be able to login with the latest link being received.` `You'll also be able to receive an error message for example in iOS, "The action code is invalid.` `This can happen if the code is malformed, expired, or has already been used" when you clicked the older links.`